# My gnuplot fit is very off, how can I improve it?

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to fit the function a/(1+b*(sin(c*x+d))**2)+e using gnuplot. The result is:

[image]

My code is

```
set terminal png
set output "lab7.png"

set xrange [7:42]
set yrange [.08:.3]
set xlabel "x"
set ylabel "I"
set title "I vs x"

f(x) = a/(1+b*(sin(c*x+d))**2)+e
fit f(x) "lab7_data.dat" via a,b,c,d,e 

plot "lab7_data.dat" t "data", f(x) t "fit"
exit
```

How can I make it fit better?

Comment: You've read http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node82.html and all its subsections, including the bit about starting values?

Comment: @NateEldredge  I dont understand how to use starting values. Could you explain it to me? Like I can guess what values a,b,c,d,e should be around, but I dont know how to use it to fit my function. Or is it saying that just vary the parameters manually?

Answer (score 0):

The first question you should ask yourself: is there a realistic chance that your data can be fitted with your function at all?

What I see is a damped oscillating function. 
With your function there will be oscillation but no damping in amplitude as function of `x`.

My first guess would be more a function like `f(x) = a/(x-b) * sin(c*x+d) + e`.

```
### fit a function
reset session

$Data <<EOD
# Data approximately from OP's post
8.968   0.119
9.901   0.180
11.915  0.220
12.921  0.240
13.931  0.252
15.905  0.251
16.867  0.243
17.888  0.229
18.974  0.196
20.005  0.157
20.917  0.133
21.998  0.111
22.905  0.099
23.978  0.095
24.882  0.092
25.954  0.091
27.024  0.094
28.982  0.130
31.940  0.203
33.854  0.213
34.923  0.218
35.995  0.216
36.956  0.212
37.920  0.198
38.944  0.177
39.978  0.132
41.000  0.114
EOD

set xrange [7:42]
set yrange [.08:.3]
set xlabel "x"
set ylabel "I"
set title "I vs x"

a=1
b=1
c=2*pi/20
d=1
e=1

# f(x) = a/(1+b*(sin(c*x+d))**2)+e      # is this an appropriate function?
f(x) = a/(x-b) * sin(c*x+d) + e         # my guess
fit f(x) $Data via a,b,c,d,e 

plot $Data t "data" w p pt 7 lc rgb "red" , f(x) t "fit"
### end of code
```

Result:

[image]

```
Final set of parameters            Asymptotic Standard Error
=======================            ==========================
a               = 3.76651          +/- 0.8605       (22.85%)
b               = -23.8952         +/- 10.11        (42.31%)
c               = 0.319073         +/- 0.003908     (1.225%)
d               = 3.0736           +/- 0.08416      (2.738%)
e               = 0.160669         +/- 0.00242      (1.506%)
```

Comment: I'm fitting to this function since theoretically the data should follow such function. But thanks, since I see in your code that you initialized the parameters, which now that I do it, I get a much better fit though with a large error.

Comment: Nice, that you showed a full working example. But suggesting a different function, only because it fits better, isn't appropriate. I hope, that the original function is the description of a related model, which shouldn't be changed at good will ;)

Comment: I completely agree. If your function is given by theory and the data doesn't fit then either you have measurement errors or the theory doesn't cover specific (sub)effects.